# tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, tweepy

I was working on a little project. I've been stuck here for some time now. I don't understand why it does not let me use the `api.update.status`. I do think I'm giving it the right arguments. Any help would be appreciated!

Picture of code below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q83zH.png

Answer (score 0):

From [the FAQ section about this in Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.4.0/faq.html#why-am-i-encountering-a-401-unauthorized-error):

> Why am I encountering a 401 Unauthorized error?
>
> If you’re using a method that performs an action on behalf of the authenticating user, e.g. `API.update_status()`, make sure your app has the write permission.
>
> After giving it the write permission, make sure to regenerate and use new credentials to utilize it.
>
> See [Twitter’s API documentation on app permissions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/app-permissions) for more information.